# How do I add a comment to the question or someone's answer?

Tags: support, comments

I am very sorry to have to ask this, but I am a complete loss.

sometimes I see a box to "add a comment"...  usually below a fresh comment, but mostly I don't, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to instigate a comment if that edit field is not already there.

Much thanks for all of your patience!

-eric

Comment: okay, on this question, i saw an "add comment" button...  but, why don't i see it on other people's questions?

Comment: Stack overflow has a site set up for questions of this sort: meta.stackoverflow.com. Don't worry about asking it there yourself, it'll get migrated there soon.

Comment: You can always comment on your own questions/answers or answers to your own questions. You need 50 rep to comment on other questions and answers

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the amount of reputation you have. You need to have at least 50 to comment on Stack Overflow. Check out the FAQ: https://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: And until you have 50 rep you'll only be able to leave comments on your own posts.  The 50 rep bit allows you to comment on any post.

Comment: That's it, thanks!  Kinda makes it hard to answer a question without being able to ask for more information...  but, i guess eventually, i'll be able to.

Comment: So, I've never understood why the limit on commenting.  Not being able to comment from the get-go actually encourages the wrong behavior (e.g. replying to threads to "respond" vs. comments) and is a barrier to new people participating in a less invasive way (perhaps allowing them to "ease" into the site...)

Comment: I agree with Joe's comment. And, by the way, I was able to add this comment on someone else's answer with a reputation of 1 on Meta Stack Overflow and a reputation of 11 on Stack Overflow. Perhaps, on Meta Stack Overflow, anyone is allowed to comment on anyone's question and answer right from the get-go?