# I do not have an answer but I have objections to the question and some answers. Where should I post?

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't comment on other posts, able to comment on own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32352/cant-comment-on-other-posts-able-to-comment-on-own)

There is a question on Stack Overflow which has been answered but there are some aspects of the answer (and even a statement in the question) that I do not agree with. When I started to type in the "Your Answer" textbox, a message was displayed saying that I should have an answer to the question and not just a comment because this is not a discussion forum. I do not have an answer but what I have to say ***is*** relevant to the question. Where and how should I add my comments?

Comment: +1, well done acquiring the 50 rep needed so quickly.

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to the site!  Once you have 50 reputation points on Stackoverflow, you will be able to post comments under any question or answer.  You will see an "add comment" link below each post.

Here is a link to the page on the "Comment Everywhere" privilege:

https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment

You can see information about all of the privileges on this page:

https://stackoverflow.com/privileges

I know it seems inconvenient, but there isn't really a workaround for this.  Luckily, it only takes 5 upvotes on answers or 10 on questions to reach 50 rep =)  You'll get there soon enough.

If there is a flagrant problem with the question or answer (it's offensive, it's not actually an answer, etc.), *flag it for moderator attention* (using the "flag" link beneath each post).  This only requires 15 reputation.  **Do not** flag it for moderator attention if it's just incorrect though.  The community will take care of that through downvotes, etc.

**Edit:** It looks like you're up to 50 rep now on SO, so this is kind of a moot point, isn't it?  Happy commenting =)

Comment: [The OP is aware of this from the comment they left here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51332/145673). I assume they are asking what they are supposed to do when they can't comment, don't have a full answer but do have something useful to contribute. Nothing? Post it as an answer anyway and have it converted by a mod?

Comment: @MartinSmith ...ohhhhhhh.  Can't believe I missed that implication.  I'll edit my answer.